# How to make ExternalProject_Add acting like ADD_SUBDIRECTORY command with cmake?

Tags: c++, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I'm creating a native library under Android Studio, and I'm hurting the following problem.

In my AndroidStudio project `CMakeLists.txt`, I have this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7.0)    

add_library(native-lib
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )    

IF(USE_EXTERNAL)
    include(ExternalProject)
    ExternalProject_Add(
        project_mylib
        DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
        SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/mylib/"
        CMAKE_ARGS
            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
    )
    add_dependencies(native-lib project_mylib)
ELSE()
    add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/mylib/)
ENDIF()    

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )   


target_link_libraries(native-lib
    ${log-lib}    
    mylib
)
```

A self-made library is located in `src/main/cpp/mylib/`, with a `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7.0)
project(lib)    
add_library(mylib SHARED lib.cpp)
INSTALL(TARGETS mylib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib
)
```

When I use the "traditional" `add_subdirectory(...)` everything goes well. But, if I use the `ExternalProject_Add(...)` version, linker is skipping the compiled `libmylib.so` library and so cannot link `mylib` to `native-lib`.

I have the following message: `skipping incompatible /home/.../app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a/lib/libmylib.so when searching for -lmylib`

My guess is that all the flags set by AndroidStudio for the root `CMakeLists.txt` are not set when the `ExternalProject` is compile leading to an incompatible shared library.

So, I wonder if there is a way to compile a cmake `ExternalProject` like it was part of the root project (sharing the same compile flags etc) ?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: `My guess is that all the flags set by AndroidStudio for the root CMakeLists.txt are not set when the ExternalProject is compile` - Exactly. Parameters of  your project are not automatically passed to External project. Pass them via *CMAKE_ARGS* option, like you pass *CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX*. Do not forget to pass toolchain (*CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE* variable).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Should I set them one by one then ? I might create a list with all global variables that are prefixed by "CMAKE_" what do you think ?

Comment: Passing all global variable to ExternalProject is rarely needed. Passing *CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE* resolves compatibility issues in most cases. If some flags are crusial for your project (like `-fPIC`), you may pass them explicitely.

Comment: Ok I'll try that, thank you !

Comment: You could also use ExternalProject to incorporate the lib directly in your current CMake project cf. http://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/ that way you share everything + you'll have access to all target. which is cool if your deps don't provide install rules and export a *Config.cmake file (e.g. abseil-cpp).

Comment: I've been looking for this kind of article for a while thanks ! What I'm actually doing is specifying `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` for each `ExternalProject_Add` so that all libraries/includes of all projects are at same location. The link you have sent me will help a lot thanks.